# Difference between scipy and numpy sobel gradient calculation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

**Setting**

I am currently trying to calcualte the image gradients with sobel filters. 
At first I used `scipy.ndimage.sobel`function via

```py
sx = ndimage.sobel(im, axis=0,mode="constant")
sy = ndimage.sobel(im, axis=1,mode="constant")
sobel = np.hypot(sx,sy)
sobel *= 255 / np.max(sobel)
```

However this only applies (3x3) sobel filter to my image, but I want to try bigger filter. Therefore I tried to calculated the image gradient with `numpy` and `scipy.signal`. First of all I tried (3x3) filter again.

```py
filter_x = np.array([[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]], dtype=np.float)
filter_y = np.array([[1,2,1], [0,0,0], [-1,-2,-1]], dtype = np.float)
sx = signal.convolve2d(im,filter_x,mode="same",boundary="symm", fillvalue=0)
sy = signal.convolve2d(im,filter_y,mode="same",boundary="symm", fillvalue=0)
sobel = np.hypot(sx,sy)
sobel *= 255 / np.max(sobel)
```

as suggestet in [this](https://fengl.org/2014/08/27/a-simple-implementation-of-sobel-filtering-in-python/) post.

**Problem**

Unfortunately these two approaches are leading to completely different results, which was already mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52947492/sobel-filter-implementation-in-scipy) question.
So I digged a little bit deeper and found that `scipy.ndimage.sobel` uses the `correlate1d` function instead of `convolve2d` or anything similar [(source code)](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L333-L367). Unfortunately it is not possible to look inside the souce code for the `correlate1d` function since its functionallty is hidden inside the already compiled `_nd_image.pyd` file in the site-packages folder of my conda enviroment. So here comes my question:

**Question**

Does anyone explicitely know, what exactly is being calculated by `correlate1d` and in what way it is comparable to `convolve2d`?

**Edit**

As already mentioned in the answer of Florian Drawitsch one should be able to replace convolution by correlation. But then again, how do these different results appear?!

Comment: You can look at the source code on [github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/src/nd_image.c#L185). And the `NI_Correlate1D` function it calls is in the ni_filters.c file in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look on that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by the method names `correlate1d` and `convolve2d` I would strongly suspect that the former computes a correlation, whereas the latter computes a convolution. What's the difference?

Generally speaking, a convolution of a signal `f` with a kernel `g` involves flipping the kernel before the operation: `f*g(-t)`

In contrast, a correlation of a signal `f` with a kernel `g` is carried out without flipping the kernel: `f*g(t)`

Applying a directional edge detection kernel (like a [sobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) kernel) using convolution should therefore result in inverted edges compared to the result using correlation. Let's test this in code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('lena.png')
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

First, let's define a sobel edge detection kernel:

```
g = np.asarray([[-1, 0, 1],
                [-2, 0, 2],
                [-1, 0, 1]])
```

Now let's first convolve the image with our kernel using sicpy's `signal.convolve2d`

```
img_convolved = signal.convolve2d(img, g)
plt.imshow(img_convolved, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

... and zoom in on a edge:

```
plt.imshow(img_convolved[100:150,100:150], cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Now, let's correlate the image with our kernel using sicpy's `signal.correlate2d`

```
img_correlated = signal.correlate2d(img, g)
plt.imshow(img_correlated, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

... and zoom in on a edge:

```
plt.imshow(img_correlated[100:150,100:150], cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Finally, let's compare the correlation result with what happens if we do a convolution with a flipped kernel:

```
img_convolved_flipped = signal.convolve2d(img, np.fliplr(g))
plt.imshow(img_convolved, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

... and zoom in on a edge:

```
plt.imshow(img_convolved_flipped[100:150,100:150], cmap='gray')
```

[image]

So, scipy's `signal.correlate2d(img, g)` is equivalent to `signal.convolve2d(img, np.fliplr(g))`

EDIT (Clarification for the 2D code example):

Please note that in the 2D case a convolution of a signal `f` with a kernel `g` involves flipping the kernel around both cardinal axes: `f*g(-t,-u)`.

Therefore, in my code I should have actually flipped the filter twice: `np.flipud(np.fliplr(g))`. I have omitted this since is not necessary for the vertically symmetric sobel filter but keep in mind that this was a special case.

Comment: Quantitatively you can do `img_correlated - img_convoled_flipped` and show that the differences are very small or zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer. Probably you would have to add, that these properties only hold, if your kernel function is symmetric or anti-symmetric and not for arbitrary kernels.

Comment: I am not sure to which properties you are referring to. If you mean the inversion, then yes this is a special property of edge detection kernels like sobel. However, the main point of my answer was to show that the result of a convolution and a correlation with flipped kernel (or vice versa) are equivalent, which always holds true

Comment: I saw your edit. You are right. What I was thinking of was convolution and correlation for general integrable functions, which is a little bit misleading, when talking about convolutions of matrices. Sorry for that and thank you again! :)

Comment: I am not sure why this would make a difference. The properties of convolution and correlation in the continuous case are completely analog to the discrete case. Instead of flipping a discrete matrix you then flip a continuous function along the cardinal axes.

Comment: Because `(f*g)(-x) = integral(f(t)g(-(x+t))dt)` for convolution and `(f**g)(x) =integral(f(t)g(x+t)dt)` for correlation. So g has to be symmetric or antisymmetric to obtain any properties.

Comment: Why not simply `(f*g)(x) = integral(f(t)g(x-t)dt)` for convolution? This is exactly the gist of it. And could you please clarify in proper mathematical terms what you mean by symmetric or anti-symmetric? Strictly mathematically speaking, a sobel kernel is not a [symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix), even though it has a orthonormal symmetry axis. And ultimately, why should the validity of these concepts depend at all on the particular kernel?

Comment: I think I understand where your confusion comes from, and I might be responsible for it because of the extremely sloppy notation I used to indicate the kernel flip. In my answer, I attempted to indicate the kernel flip by writing g(-x) which of course looks like the signal (or image) is flipped. I should have used a different index here, like g(-t), since the signal is not flipped at all, just the order in which the values of the kernel are indexed (or the integration direction in the continuous case). I will update my answer to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: `g` is symmetric iff `g(x)=g(-x)`, `g` is antisymmetric iff `g(x)=-g(-x)` for all `x`. If we would have such a property, we would obtain that `(f*g)(-x)=(f**g)(x)`, if `g` is symmetric or `(f*g)(-x)=-(f**g)(x)`, if `g` is antisymmetric. That's what I was talking about, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: If you mean with `(f*g)(-x)=(f**g)(x)` that you can you can obtain the equivalent of a result of a correlation by flipping the result of a convolution, then this is always wrong, even if your kernel has this property! Just try it with any signal and any kernel!

Comment: I think our discussion gets out of the scope of my initial question. However, assume `g` is symmetric with the meaning of the above definition. Then we have that `(f*g)(-x) = integral(f(t)g(-x-t)dt)=integral(f(t)g(-(x+t))dt=integral(f(t)g(x+t)dt)=(f**g)(x)`. So if `g` is symmetric or antisymmetric then convolution and correlation are equivalent up to sign and flip.

Comment: Hm, probably we are just talking past each other. Let's leave it at that ok? :)